# TableViewCells and Array of Dictionaries

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am having trouble understanding how to populate my table with all the dates. returns only the day 9-1-2012 not 8-31-2012. I have tried a few things like using my days and slots in numberofrowssection. I am thinking it has something to do with .count but am not seeing where. But I have not figured it out yet. It still is only posting 9/1 dictionary. How do I display all the array of dictionaries in tableviewcell, I hope I am making sense, picture attached.
My code:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSDictionary* myslots =[json objectForKey:@"slots"];
    NSLog(@"allslots: %@", myslots);

    for (NSString *slotKey in myslots.allKeys) {
    NSDictionary *slot = [myslots valueForKey:slotKey];
       UPDATED:
        self.timesArray = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *myDays in slot){

        if ([[myDays objectForKey:@"isReservable"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]])

           [self.timesArray addObject:[myDays objectForKey:@"begin"]];
         //NSLog(@"This is the times count: %@", timesArray.count);
    }

       NSLog(@"These are the times avail: %@", self.timesArray);          

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Here is what that looks like:

```
2012-08-31 16:34:57.074 GBSB[780:15b03] These are the times avail: {(
    "2012-08-31 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 13:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 14:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 15:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-08-31 16:00:00 America/Los_Angeles"
)}
2012-08-31 16:34:57.074 GBSB[780:15b03] These are the times avail: {(
    "2012-09-01 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-09-01 10:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-09-01 11:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-09-01 12:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-09-01 13:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-09-01 14:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-09-01 15:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "2012-09-01 16:00:00 America/Los_Angeles"
)}
```

Here is what I have tried
in .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableOrderedSet *timesArray;
```

.m

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.timesArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    //cell.textLabel.text = timesArray;
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.timesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
```

Here is a pic
[image: only displaying one dictionary]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are close, because your array has all of the values, just not at the same time.  Try moving self.timesArray = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init]; up before the for loop so that it is only initialized once.  Also, move the final NSLog and tableView reloadData down
like this:

```
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSDictionary* myslots =[json objectForKey:@"slots"];
    self.timesArray = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"allslots: %@", myslots);

    for (NSString *slotKey in myslots.allKeys) {
        NSDictionary *slot = [myslots valueForKey:slotKey];
       UPDATED:
        for (NSDictionary *myDays in slot){

            if ([[myDays objectForKey:@"isReservable"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]])

               [self.timesArray addObject:[myDays objectForKey:@"begin"]];
            //NSLog(@"This is the times count: %@", timesArray.count);
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"These are the times avail: %@", self.timesArray);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I new I was close. It all starts to blur after a little while haha

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm new to stackoverflow.com, so thanks for providing me the opportunity to earn some credibility. :-)