# How do I get my array of dictionaries to populate my tableview?

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary

I think I'm close, but I just need a little direction to help to finish. I want to populate a tableview with my data, but I'm stumped.

I have two arrays of dictionaries that hold user data: daily jobs, and weekly jobs.

**Array #1:**

```
let finalDailyJobsArray = [JobsAndHabits(name: "counters", multiplier: 1.0, assigned: "Sophie", order: 0),
                       JobsAndHabits(name: "bedroom", multiplier: 1.0, assigned: "Sophie", order: 1),
                       JobsAndHabits(name: "bathrooms", multiplier: 1.0, assigned: "Allan", order: 2),
                       JobsAndHabits(name: "laundry", multiplier: 1.0, assigned: "Mother", order: 3),
                       JobsAndHabits(name: "living room", multiplier: 1.0, assigned: "Father", order: 4),
                       JobsAndHabits(name: "dining room", multiplier: 1.0, assigned: "Father", order: 5),
                       JobsAndHabits(name: "dishes", multiplier: 1.0, assigned: "Allan", order: 6)]
```

**And array #2:**

```
let finalWeeklyJobsArray = [JobsAndHabits(name: "wash windows", multiplier: 1.0, assigned: "Father", order: 1),
                        JobsAndHabits(name: "weed garden", multiplier: 1.0, assigned: "Father", order: 0),
                        JobsAndHabits(name: "sweep porch", multiplier: 1.0, assigned: "Father", order: 2),
                        JobsAndHabits(name: "clean pool", multiplier: 1.0, assigned: "Mother", order: 4),
                        JobsAndHabits(name: "dusting & cobwebs", multiplier: 1.0, assigned: "Sophie", order: 3)]
```

In addition, I have two variables that also hold single bits of info.

**Single variables:**

```
let inspectionParent = "Mother"     // this is a daily job
let paydayParent = "Father"         // this is a weekly job
```

I want to put these into a tableview with a section for each user. It will look like this:

[image: users job list]

As you can see, I figured out how to get the user images and user names out of my arrays, as well as how to determine the number of sections to create, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to customize the `cellForRowAt` property.

I want to list each individual's daily jobs and weekly jobs beneath their name. I'm guessing the trick lies in figuring out how to iterate over the arrays using the `indexPath.row` functionality, but so far my efforts haven't worked. Can someone please step in and help me?

What I've tried:

**Attempt #1:** I think this is the right direction, but I'm not sure how to get the cells to coordinate, or even where to put this code.

```
let userNames2 = finalUsersArray.map({ return $0.firstName }).sorted()
let jobAssignments2 = finalWeeklyJobsArray.map({ return $0.assigned }).sorted()
let userNames3 = finalUsersArray.filter({ return $0.firstName == "Father" })
```

**Attempt #2:** This repeated the same data in each section, which isn't what I want.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! JobSummaryCellB
    if User.finalUsersArray[indexPath.row].firstName == JobsAndHabits.finalWeeklyJobsArray[indexPath.row].assigned {
        cell.userNameLabel.text = JobsAndHabits.finalWeeklyJobsArray[indexPath.row].name
    }
    return cell
```

**Attempt #3:** Totally didn't work.

```
cell.userNameLabel.text = User.finalUsersArray.filter({ return $0.firstName == "Father" })
```

**Attempt #4:** Also didn't work (returned error)

```
if JobsAndHabits.finalWeeklyJobsArray[indexPath.row].assigned == User.finalUsersArray[indexPath] {
        cell.userNameLabel.text = JobsAndHabits.finalWeeklyJobsArray[indexPath.row].name
```

I found these articles, but couldn't figure out how to adapt them to my situation: [article1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524551/populate-table-section-and-rows-from-array-of-dictionaries), [article2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823865/not-populating-tableview-with-structure-array), [article3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232385/tableviewcells-and-array-of-dictionaries)

Any help would be awesome!!

**Edit #1:**

Here is my `numberOfSections` method:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return User.finalUsersArray.count
}
```

And my `viewForHeaderInSection` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell") as! JobSummaryCell
    cell.headerImage.image = User.finalUsersArray[section].photo
    cell.headerLabel.text = User.finalUsersArray[section].firstName
    return cell
}
```

And my two Structs:

```
struct User {
    var photo: UIImage
    var firstName: String
    var birthday: Int
    var passcode: Int
    var gender: String
    var childParent: String
}

struct JobsAndHabits {
    var name: String
    var multiplier: Double
    var assigned: String
    var order: Int

    static var finalDailyJobsArray = [JobsAndHabits]()
    static var finalWeeklyJobsArray = [JobsAndHabits]()

    static var inspectionParent = ""
    static var paydayParent = ""
}
```

**Update #2:** How finalUsersArray is populated.

```
static func loadMembers() {
    let firebaseUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(firebaseUser!.uid)
    ref.child("members").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            if let snap = item as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                if let value = snap.value as? [String : Any] {
                    let birthday = value["birthday"] as! Int
                    let childParent = value["childParent"] as! String
                    let firstName = value["firstName"] as! String
                    let gender = value["gender"] as! String
                    let passcode = value["passcode"] as! Int
                    let profileImageUrl = value["profileImageUrl"] as! String
                    // get images
                    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: profileImageUrl)
                    storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                        let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
                        let user = User(photo: pic!,
                                        firstName: firstName,
                                        birthday: birthday,
                                        passcode: passcode,
                                        gender: gender,
                                        childParent: childParent)
                        finalUsersArray.append(user)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: can you show the code for `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRows` methods?

Comment: Yes, please see updated code.

Comment: I put in my code for `numberOfSections`, but I don't have the code for `numberOfRowsInSection` because I couldn't figure it out. Each user will have a different number of daily and weekly jobs assigned, and I'm not sure how to get that number...

Comment: where are you adding elements to `finalUsersArray` ? can you show that part of code?

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe what I do is create another set of arrays. Maybe create an array with just userNames and assignments (daily and weekly) from the initial data. Thoughts?

Comment: You are getting the `finalWeeklyJobsArray ` from the firebase as well or is it hardcoded?

Comment: Yes, all data is being parsed from a database download.

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: I'm very close. @ViniApp got me the code that got me close. I'm busy tweaking his code to make mine work, but it looks promising. :-)

Comment: Yes, I got the code to work, and it's working well. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
    let dailyJobAssignments = JobsAndHabits.finalDailyJobsArray.filter({ return $0.assigned == User.finalUsersArray[section].firstName }).count 
    let weeklyJobAssignments = JobsAndHabits.finalWeeklyJobsArray.filter({ return $0.assigned == User.finalWeeklyJobsArray[section].firstName }).count 
    return dailyJobAssignments+weeklyJobAssignments
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! JobSummaryCellB
    let dailyJobAssignments = JobsAndHabits.finalDailyJobsArray.filter({ return $0.assigned == User.finalUsersArray[indexPath.section].firstName })
    let weeklyJobAssignments = JobsAndHabits.finalWeeklyJobsArray.filter({ return $0.assigned == User.finalWeeklyJobsArray[indexPath.section].firstName })
    let jobAssignments = dailyJobAssignments + weeklyJobAssignments
    cell.userNameLabel.text = jobAssignments[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Okay, so just reading the code seems like this is very close to what I need. However, when I try it, I get an `Index out of range` error. Also, I can't implement the `sorted()` method at the end. It also gives me a `missing parameter` error.

Comment: Sweet! I got the `numberOfRowsInSection` to work using your code. It now reads: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let jobAssignments = JobsAndHabits.finalDailyJobsArray.filter({ return $0.assigned == User.finalUsersArray[section].firstName }).count
        
        return jobAssignments
    }`

Comment: Aaaaaaaannnndddd...got the `cellForRowAt` to work for daily jobs...NOW, how do I add in the rows for the `weeklyJobs`??

Comment: Wow. Didn't know about the `zip` function. Pretty nifty! Thanks for your help.

Comment: But now I'm getting an error that says the zipped sequence 'has no subscript members'. This is on the line `cell.userNameLabel.text = jobAssignments[indexPath.row].name`. Does that mean the zipped arrays aren't compatible? If so, how would I fix that? Because they're both of type `JobsAndHabits` struct. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So If I understand your problem you just want to customize how your cells is going to be displayed in your TableView.
First of all, you have to indicate 2 informations to your TableView :

- How many sections do you want to have ? In your case it will be equal to how many individual's o you have.

> **func numberOfSections(in: UITableView)** Asks the data source to
>   return the number of sections in the table view.

- How many rows do you need for each section ? In your case it will be equal to how many jobs an individual have. (Daily + weekly jobs)

> **func tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int)** Tells the data
>   source to return the number of rows in a given section of a table
>   view. Required.

Then to customize your cells you need to :

- Create a class for your custom cell. You use this identifier `"customCell"` but did you have a class to represent the design of your cell ?
- Link your custom cell class to prototype cells of your table view within your storyboard
- Connect outlets and actions from your custom cell to your custom cell class
- Finally in the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` just configure your cell using your outlets...

Comment: I actually figured out how many sections. That's just the number of users. See updated code: `User.finalUsersArray.count`. It's the `numberOfRowsInSection` as well as the `cellForRowAt` methods that have me stumped. I don't know how to calculate those.

Comment: And yes, I have already created the custom class for the cell, as you can see in the code: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! JobSummaryCellB`. The custom class is `JobSummaryCellB`. What I need is the code to put in that method...